# Python threading.local() not working in Thread class

Tags: python, multithreading, local

In Python3.6, I use threading.local() to store some status for thread.
Here is a simple example to explain my question:

```
    import threading

    class Test(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.local = threading.local()
            self.local.test = 123

        def run(self):
            print(self.local.test)
```

When I start this thread:

```
t = Test()
t.start()
```

Python gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'test'
```

It seems the **test** atrribute can not access out of the **__init__** function scope, because I can print the value in the **__init__** function after local set attribute **test=123**.

Is it necessary to use threading.local object inside in a Thread subclass? I think the instance attributes of a Thread instance could keep the attributes thread safe.

Anyway, **why the threading.local object not work as expected between instance function?**

Comment: If you want to attach data to a `Thread` object in a way that's visible from all threads, you don't need `threading.local`. Just assign to the `Thread`'s instance variables directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-local-data:

> The instance’s values will be different for separate threads.

`Test.__init__` executes in the caller's thread (e.g. the thread where `t = Test()` executes). Yes, it's good place to *create* thread-local storage (TLS).

But when `t.run` executes, it will have completely diffferent contents -- *the contents accessible only within the thread `t`*.

TLS is good when You need to share data in scope of current thread. It like just a local variable inside a function -- but for threads. When the thread finishes execution -- TLS disappears.

For inter-thread communication [Futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) can be a good choice. Some others are *Conditional variables*, *events*, etc. See [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#event-objects) docs page.

Answer (score 4):

When you constructed your thread you were using a DIFFERENT thread.  when you execute the run method on the thread you are starting a NEW thread.  that thread does not yet have a thread local variable set.  this is why you do not have your attribute it was set on the thread constructing the thread object and not the thread running the object.